# BadHeaderError("Header values can't contain newlines (got %r)" % value) in drf_social_oauth2

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, google-identity

**Describe the bug**

I got the access_token from google which I'm supposed to use to authenticate users. Everything works fine when the user is authenticating for the first time. But when the user logs out and tries to login again, it gives this wired error.

This never happened when I was using the old gapi for login. I am currently using the new recommended GSI google provided.

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Go to [Google playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to get an access token
2. Send the details to /auth/convert-token endpoint and make sure the user is registered in the database.
3. Try sending the same credentials to the same endpoint.
   **NB:** it doesn't matter whether it's a new access_token. as long as it belongs to the same user, the error will be the response.

**Expected behavior**

A response with JSON data of tokens generated by the backend

**Screenshots**

[A screenshot of the error in vscode thunder client.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytuih.png)

- Django Version: 4.0.1
- drf-social-oauth2: 1.2.1
- Google Auth system: New Google Identity Services

**Additional context**

I used to work with the Old gapi.$Auth system.

The issue appears to be coming from ConvertTokenView class in site-packages/drf_social_oauth2.py. When a user registers for the first time, these are the headers:

```bash
dict_items([('Content-Type', 'application/json'), ('Cache-Control', 'no-store'), ('Pragma', 'no-cache')])
```

when the same user tries to access convert-token endpoint, a `PS1` header is added(which contains the badHeader) together with other headers. Below is the full list of headers:

```bash
dict_items([
('USER', 'nizzy'), 
('__CFBundleIdentifier', 'com.microsoft.VSCode'), 
('COMMAND_MODE', 'unix2003'), 
('LOGNAME', 'nizzy'), 
('PATH', '/Users/nizzy/Documents/django_projects/unicart_django/unicart_market/venv/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/nizzy/Documents/django_projects/unicart_django/unicart_market/venv/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Users/nizzy/dev/flutter/bin:/Users/nizzy/.npm-global/bin:/Users/nizzy/dev/flutter/bin:/Users/nizzy/.npm-global/bin'),
('SSH_AUTH_SOCK', '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.9ZW0MlkXPb/Listeners'), 
('SHELL', '/bin/zsh'), ('HOME', '/Users/nizzy'), ('__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING', '0x1F5:0x0:0x0'), 
('TMPDIR', '/var/folders/t1/97b4p4_116l5yvb9lws3qtj40000gn/T/'), 
('XPC_SERVICE_NAME', '0'), 
('XPC_FLAGS', '0x0'), 
('ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP', 'undefined'), 
('PWD', '/Users/nizzy/Documents/django_projects/unicart_django/unicart_market'), ('APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL', 'true'), 
('MANPATH', '/opt/homebrew/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/local/MacGPG2/share/man:/opt/homebrew/share/man:'), ('INFOPATH', '/opt/homebrew/share/info:/opt/homebrew/share/info:'), ('HOMEBREW_PREFIX', '/opt/homebrew'), 
('LC_CTYPE', 'UTF-8'), ('TERM', 'xterm-256color'), ('GPG_TTY', 'not a tty'), ('ZSH', '/Users/nizzy/.oh-my-zsh'), ('TERM_SESSION_ID', 'DD29542B-0253-4567-B80E-31F4499A024B'), ('P9K_SSH', '0'), ('HOMEBREW_CELLAR', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar'), ('SHLVL', '3'), ('HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY', '/opt/homebrew'), ('TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION', '1.67.2'), ('PAGER', 'less'), ('_P9K_TTY', '/dev/ttys000'), ('LESS', '-R'), ('LSCOLORS', 'Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad'), ('TERM_PROGRAM', 'vscode'), ('P9K_TTY', 'old'), ('LANG', 'en_GB.UTF-8'), ('COLORTERM', 'truecolor'), ('VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE', '/var/folders/t1/97b4p4_116l5yvb9lws3qtj40000gn/T/vscode-git-d7ee048a49.sock'), ('VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE', '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron'), ('VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS', '--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node'), ('VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN', '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js'), ('GIT_ASKPASS', '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh'), ('OLDPWD', '/Users/nizzy/Documents/django_projects/unicart_django/unicart_market'), 

('PS1', '(venv) ${$((_p9k_on_expand()))+}%{${_p9k__raw_msg-}${_p9k__raw_msg::=}%}${(e)_p9k_t[7]}${_p9k__1-${${:-${_p9k__d::=0}${_p9k__rprompt::=${_p9k__1r-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=}}+}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=8}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(|0)}:+10}}${_p9k__n:=11}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1r:+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%k%f${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%f}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%f}${_p9k__i::=1}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}${${:-"${${(%):-%j}:#0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=""}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=12}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(|0)}:+14}}${_p9k__n:=15}${_p9k__v::=\uf013}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rbackground_jobs+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__v}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{070\\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%F{070\\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%F{070\\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${#P9K_PYENV_PYTHON_VERSION}:#0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=unicart_market}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=92}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(|0)}:+94}}${_p9k__n:=95}${_p9k__v::=\ue73c}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rvirtualenv+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__v}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{037\\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%F{037\\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%F{037\\}}${_p9k__i::=6}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${${(%):-%#}:#\\#}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=%n@%m}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=16}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(|0)}:+18}}${_p9k__n:=19}${_p9k__c::=}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rcontext+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{180\\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%F{180\\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%F{180\\}}${_p9k__i::=31}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${${(%):-%#}:#\\%}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=%B%n@%m}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=20}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(|0)}:+22}}${_p9k__n:=23}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rcontext+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{178\\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%F{178\\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%F{178\\}}${_p9k__i::=31}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=12:18:27}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=24}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(|0)}:+26}}${_p9k__n:=27}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rtime+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{066\\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%k%F{066\\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%k%F{066\\}}${_p9k__i::=42}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}$_p9k__sss%b%k%f}}${_p9k__lprompt::=${_p9k__1l-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=%f}}+}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::="%{d%}${:-"%B%F{039}"}${(Q)${:-"\\\\~"}}${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}/${${${_p9k__d:#-*}:+Documents}:-${:-"%F{103}"}Doc${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}${$((_p9k__d+=6))+}}/${${${_p9k__d:#-*}:+django_projects}:-${:-"%F{103}"}d${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}${$((_p9k__d+=14))+}}/${:-"%B%F{039}"}unicart_django${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}/${:-"%B%F{039}"}unicart_market${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}%{d%}"}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=28}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+30}}${_p9k__n:=31}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1ldir+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{031\\}${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{\\}}${_p9k__ss::= }${_p9k__sss::=%F{\\}}${_p9k__i::=1}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}${(e)_p9k__vcs}${${:-"${${:-$_p9k__keymap.$_p9k__zle_state}:#(vicmd.*|vivis.*|vivli.*|*.*overwrite*)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=❯}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=32}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+34}}${_p9k__n:=35}${_p9k__c::="❯"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1lprompt_char+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{076\\}${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{\\}}${_p9k__ss::= }${_p9k__sss::=%F{\\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${${:-$_p9k__keymap.$_p9k__zle_state}:#(vicmd.*|vivis.*|vivli.*|*.*insert*)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=▶}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=36}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+38}}${_p9k__n:=39}${_p9k__c::="▶"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1lprompt_char+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{076\\}${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{\\}}${_p9k__ss::= }${_p9k__sss::=%F{\\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${:-$_p9k__keymap$_p9k__region_active}:#vicmd0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=❮}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=40}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+42}}${_p9k__n:=43}${_p9k__c::="❮"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1lprompt_char+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{076\\}${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{\\}}${_p9k__ss::= }${_p9k__sss::=%F{\\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${:-$_p9k__keymap$_p9k__region_active}:#(vicmd1|vivis?|vivli?)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=Ⅴ}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=44}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+46}}${_p9k__n:=47}${_p9k__c::="V"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\r}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1lprompt_char+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%k%F{076\\}${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{\\}}${_p9k__ss::= }${_p9k__sss::=%F{\\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=}}+}}}%b%k$_p9k__sss%b%k%f${:-" %b%k%f"}}}}+}${(e)_p9k_t[6]}${${_p9k__h::=40.}+}${${_p9k__d::=$((_p9k__m-_p9k__h))}+}${_p9k__lprompt/\\%\\{d\\%\\}*\\%\\{d\\%\\}/${_p9k__1ldir-${:-"%B%F{039}"}${(Q)${:-"\\\\~"}}${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}/${${${_p9k__d:#-*}:+Documents}:-${:-"%F{103}"}Doc${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}${$((_p9k__d+=6))+}}/${${${_p9k__d:#-*}:+django_projects}:-${:-"%F{103}"}d${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}${$((_p9k__d+=14))+}}/${:-"%B%F{039}"}unicart_django${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}/${:-"%B%F{039}"}unicart_market${:-"%b%k%F{031}"}}}${${_p9k__m::=$((_p9k__d+_p9k__h))}+}}${${COLUMNS::=$_p9k__clm}+}'), 

('VIRTUAL_ENV', '/Users/nizzy/Documents/django_projects/unicart_django/unicart_market/venv'), 
('_', '/Users/nizzy/Documents/django_projects/unicart_django/unicart_market/venv/bin/python3'), ('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings'), ('TZ', 'UTC'), ('RUN_MAIN', 'true'), ('SERVER_NAME', '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa'), ('GATEWAY_INTERFACE', 'CGI/1.1'), ('SERVER_PORT', '8000'), ('REMOTE_HOST', ''), ('CONTENT_LENGTH', '466'), ('SCRIPT_NAME', ''), ('SERVER_PROTOCOL', 'HTTP/1.1'), ('SERVER_SOFTWARE', 'WSGIServer/0.2'), ('REQUEST_METHOD', 'POST'), ('PATH_INFO', '/auth/convert-token/'), ('QUERY_STRING', ''), ('REMOTE_ADDR', '127.0.0.1'), ('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'), ('HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)'), ('HTTP_ACCEPT', '*/*'), ('HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING', 'gzip, deflate, br'), ('HTTP_COOKIE', 'access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6Ik5XMXhFVmZvcWpHUG9VZ0M3aEkwWjBrbzFtTjNBdyJ9.G59Jm7yArLY3OOmkQGVA2wDVg_BHXSdKoeAr176CGQc; refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6Ind2dXhUdXc5bFZrZzhROTJpem0xMXlJYVZMZTR4ZSJ9.9FoRcaIj7XYD-c7m_f5N9RD6G24DGDaLrskKpukXtfA; is_authenticated=True; csrftoken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; sessionid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'), ('HTTP_HOST', 'localhost:8000'), ('HTTP_CONNECTION', 'close'), ('wsgi.version', (1, 0)), ('wsgi.run_once', False), ('wsgi.url_scheme', 'http'), ('wsgi.multithread', True), ('wsgi.multiprocess', False), ('wsgi.file_wrapper', <class 'wsgiref.util.FileWrapper'>), ('CSRF_COOKIE', 'npCiSfkvcxo0ByfWyjdOJQELZFrxNIUQn0xYQN39s74P32oPtUP0OkiIg8aLbaSI')])
```